# Insert failure in unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have an unordered map defined as (within an ordered map):

```
std::map<xxx, std::unordered_map <Key, Data,Hasher, Equals>> umap_;
```

The hash function is basically fnv:

```
static inline size_t
hash (const void *data_ptr, int len)
{
    .....
    return hv % 0xffffffff;
}
```

The insert is done as follows:

```
std::pair<
            std::unordered_map<Key,Data,Hasher, Equals>::itr,
            bool> ret;

ret = umap_[xxx].insert(
            std::pair<Key, Data>(key, data));
```

What I'm seeing is, for some cases even though the generated hash is unique, the insert fails. And when I check the return iterator, it has some key, which was inserted with a totally different hash.

What am I missing here? Is it something to do with the 32-bit hash that is being generated, and it is not working with my unordered map hs table

Thanks!

Adding the hasher and the comparator

```
struct Hasher
{
    std::size_t operator()(const Key& k) const
    {
        return k->Hash();
    }
};

struct Equals {
    bool operator() (const Key& left, const Key& right) const
        { return !(left->Comp(*right)); }
};
```

The Hash() is a virtual function in the class:

```
    class <blah> : public <blah>    {
            protected:
                uint32_t                                 slotNum;
            public:
        .....
        .....
    virtual bool Comp(const Key& in) const
    {
        ...
        if (slotNum != in.slotNum) { return (slotNum < in.slotNum); }

        return (FALSE);
    }


    virtual size_t Hash() const
    {
        ....

        hash32 = hash(key_data_buffer, key_size);

        return hash32;
    }
```

Comment: Unless you have a special reason to, don't make non-class inline functions also static. Don't use C-style casts. Use `static_cast` here, which will then not compile, until you add a const, which is good.

Comment: Show us the hasher and the comparator.

Comment: T.C, added the hasher and comparator.

Comment: Your comparator seems off; it should return `true` if they are equal and `false` otherwise. Your code appears to return `true` even if `slotNum > aIn.slotNum`

Comment: T.C, Though Compare() returns that, the eventual comparator KeyClassEquals() returns !(lhs->compare(*rhs)).. Or, what am I missing?

Comment: @SimpleCoder (Use a @ in front or it won't ping me.) The virtual `Compare()` function returns essentially `slotNum < aIn.slotNum`. `KeyClassEquals` negates that, and returns essentially `lhs->slotnum >= rhs->slotNum`. It should return `lhs->slotnum == rhs->slotNum`.

Comment: @T.C. Got resolved after I added an equals method. So, it was indeed the compare code. Thanks!